# How to set a counter like this?

Tags: numbering

I want to set a counter like picture

[image]

I only can do

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\pagestyle{empty}

\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
%\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\begin{document}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. 
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. 
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. \end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\end{document}
```

How to set a counter like this picture?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\pagestyle{empty}

\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
%\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{pro}{Problem}
\newcounter{probtype}
\renewcommand\theprobtype{\alph{probtype}}
\renewcommand\thepro{\arabic{pro}\theprobtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. 
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. 
\end{pro}
\setcounter{probtype}{1}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. \end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\setcounter{probtype}{2}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\setcounter{probtype}{0}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Very nice and simple, +1.

Answer (score 7):

I am pretty sure I learnt this trick from egreg on the chatroom. Here goes my solution (I'll try to come up with a little more sophisticated solution, but no promises there). Note that this is not very amenable if you are also looking forward to using the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{proaux}{Problem \protect\pronumber}
\newenvironment{pro}[1]{\def\pronumber{#1}\proaux}{\endproaux}
\begin{document}
\begin{pro}{1}
  This is a problem!
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}{2a}
  This is a problem!
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}{3a}
  This is a problem!
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}{2b}
  This is a problem!
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}{3b}\label{pro:3b}
  This is a problem!
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}{4}
  This is a problem!
\end{pro}
In problem \ref{pro:3b}, you should have noticed that 
\end{document}
```

[image: pro.png]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a different solution with `pgfkeys`.

One can:

- start a sub problem with `start sub problem` (this prints `2a` for example);
- continue a sub problem with `continue sub problem` (this prints `2b` for example).

These two keys should be used for "continuous" sub problems. If instead, sub problems are no "continuous":

- `start custom sub problem` again starts the list, i.e prints `6a`;
- `continue sub problem list` continues the list, i.e prints `7a`;
- `continue custom sub problem` changes sub problem, i.e prints `6b`.

An example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,standard,thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pagestyle{empty}

\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}

\newcounter{subproblem}
\newcounter{auxproblem}

\pgfkeys{/theorem prob/.cd,
  start sub problem/.code={%
    \setcounter{subproblem}{1}
    \renewcommand{\theprob}{\arabic{prob}\alph{subproblem}}
  },
  continue sub problem/.code={
    \stepcounter{subproblem}
    \addtocounter{prob}{-1}
    \renewcommand{\theprob}{\arabic{prob}\alph{subproblem}}
  },
  start custom sub problem/.code={
    \setcounter{subproblem}{1}
    \renewcommand{\theprob}{\arabic{prob}\alph{subproblem}}
    \setcounter{auxproblem}{\value{prob}}
  },
  continue sub problem list/.code={    
    \renewcommand{\theprob}{\arabic{prob}\alph{subproblem}}
  },
  continue custom sub problem/.code={
    \setcounter{prob}{\value{auxproblem}}
    \stepcounter{subproblem}
    \renewcommand{\theprob}{\arabic{prob}\alph{subproblem}}
  },
}

\newenvironment{pro}[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/theorem prob/.cd,#1}
  \begin{prob}
}{%
  \end{prob}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. 
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. 
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem. 
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[start sub problem]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue sub problem]\label{pro:4b}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue sub problem]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[start custom sub problem]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue sub problem list]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue sub problem list]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue custom sub problem]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue sub problem list]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue sub problem list]\label{pro:8b}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue custom sub problem]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue sub problem list]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}[continue sub problem list]
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem.
\end{pro}
\begin{pro}
This is a Problem which refers to problem~\ref{pro:4b} and to problem~\ref{pro:8b}.
\end{pro}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]