# Dividing chapters into ch. 1, ch. 2a, ch. 2b, ch. 3 etc

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

I'm typesetting a book and one of the chapters separates into two chapters so I need it to count like so:

```
chapter 1
---------

chapter 2a
----------

chapter 2b
----------

chapter 3
---------

chapter 4
---------
```

I saw an almost solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63112/numbering-sections-as-1a-1b-2a-2b-etc). But this solution doesn't allow me to continue with my non-separated chapter counting.

This is chapters only, the sections are not numbered, and I'm using the `book` class with the `hyperref` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is it that chapter only? Are you using `hyperref`? What document class?

Comment: I think the answers here can be made to work in this case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110424/10679 (So, I'd regard this as an abstract duplicate, although I am not flagging it as such, for now.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using one of the standard document class that provides `\chapter` (like [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) or [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)), then the following works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
%\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\newcounter{subchapter}\renewcommand{\thesubchapter}{\alph{subchapter}}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\newcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\@afterheading}{\updatechaptercounter\@afterheading}{}{}% Regular patch of \@chapter
%\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{\@afterheading}{\updatechaptercounter\@afterheading}{}{}% Hyperref patch of \@chapter
\makeatother
\providecommand{\theHchapter}{}%
\newcommand{\startsubchapters}{%
  \setcounter{subchapter}{0}% Reset sub-chapter numbering
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thesubchapter}% Update chapter number display
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thesubchapter}% Update chapter number display (for hyperref)
  \renewcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}}% Update chapter number
  \let\oldchapter\chapter%
  \renewcommand{\chapter}{\stepcounter{subchapter}\oldchapter}% Increment subchapter
}
\newcommand{\stopsubchapters}{%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% Reset chapter numbering
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% Reset chapter numbering (for hyperref)
  \let\chapter\oldchapter% Restore regular \chapter command
  \renewcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{}% Clear chapter counter update
  \stepcounter{chapter}% Update chapter counter
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\startsubchapters
\chapter{Second sub-chapter}
\chapter{Second sub-chapter}
\stopsubchapters
\chapter{Third chapter}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}
\end{document}
```

The idea behind this solution is to patch `\@chapter` and insert a special macro `\updatechaptercounter`. This macro is then redefined in a specific way, depending on whether you start the sub-chapter numbering (`\startsubchapters`) or stop it (`\stopsubchapters`).

If you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as well, then you need to update the patch as indicated in the above MWE.

Comment: look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314245/making-sub-chapters too

Comment: Thanks mate !!!!