# Making sub-chapters

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm writing a book and I wanted to add sub-chapters like :

Chapter 1

Chapter 2

Chapter 3.1

Chapter 3.2

Chapter 3.3

Chapter 4

I've quite found an answer [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111845/dividing-chapters-into-ch-1-ch-2a-ch-2b-ch-3-etc/111867#111867) but it's not working the way I wanted. Is someone having an idea ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is wrong with `\section`??? A `\section` is a `sub`chapter and if the section counter is correctly set up, it's `3.1`, `3.2`, `3.3` etc. Or redefine the `chapter` counter

Comment: Please tell us how a sub-chapter is supposed to differ from a section. Please also provide more details about how/why the earlier answer you've provided a link to is "not working the way I wanted." What exactly do you want?

Comment: @Mico: Too late, egreg closed it already ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A manual setup, not very convenient, by storing the chapter number and restoring it later on.

(In this example, the chapter number width in the ToC should be increased, e.g. with `\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{5pt}` from `tocloft` package)

```
\documentclass{book}



\newcounter{subchapterusage}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@thechapter\thechapter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{subchapterusage}% Reset the chapter counter if subchapterusage is stepped

\newcommand{\PrepareForSubchapterUsage}{%
  \xdef\chapvalue{\the\numexpr\number\value{chapter}+1}
  \stepcounter{subchapterusage}%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\chapvalue.\latex@@thechapter}
}

\newcommand{\RestoreToChapterUsage}{%
  \setcounter{chapter}{\chapvalue}
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\latex@@thechapter}
}

\makeatother



\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foobar}

\PrepareForSubchapterUsage
\chapter{Intermediate Chapter with Strange Counting}
\section{Foo section}
\chapter{Another intermediate Chapter with Strange Counting}

\chapter{Yet another intermediate Chapter with Strange Counting}
\RestoreToChapterUsage
\chapter{Foo continued}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course `\section` is much easier!

Comment: Thank you, it's working very well, doing exactly what I was looking for. I just had to increase the width of the chapter and the sections into the ToC with your suggestion.

Comment: I know that    \section works well, but I already use it inside my chapters

Comment: @BastienAntoine: I see -- but actually, there's no concept of `subchapters` actually. Happy TeXing anyway!